# getent group not returning domain groups

Tags: permissions, samba, active-directory, groups

I want to allow Windows AD users to access files shares on my Ubuntu Server (16.04.1).
I followed this tutorial : 
[Samba Shares with Active Directory Login on Ubuntu 12.04](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/SAMBA_Share_with_Active_Directory_Login_on_Ubuntu_12.04.html)
I followed every step. I found out i needed to install `libnss-winbind` & `libpam-winbind` after some trouble shooting. 
I re-did `pam-auth-update` after installing those last packages.

I get a valid itcket when i `kinit` a user,
`wbinfo -u` works,
**`wbinfo -g` works,**
`getent passwd` returns local **and** AD users,

### **but `getent group` only returns local groups.**

And when i want to `chgrp -R 'Domain Users' /sharing/`, I get : `chgrp: invalid group: ‘Domain Users’`

krb5.conf =

```
[libdefaults]
  ticket_lifetime = 24h
  default_realm = EXAMPLE.LOCAL
  forwardable = true

[realms]
  EXAMPLE.LOCAL = {
    kdc = 192.168.254.3
    default_domain = EXAMPLE.LOCAL
  }

[domain_realm]
  .example.local = EXAMPLE.LOCAL
  example.local = EXAMPLE.LOCAL

[kdc]
  profile = /etc/krb5kdc/kdc.conf

[appdefaults]
  pam = {
    debug = false
    ticket_lifetime = 36000
    renew_lifetime = 36000
    forwardable = true
    krb4_convert = false
  }

[logging]
  kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
  admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmin.log
  default = FILE:/var/log/krb5lib.log
```

smb.conf =

```
[global]
    # No .tld
    workgroup = EXAMPLE
    # Active Directory System
    security = ads
    # With .tld
    realm = EXAMPLE.LOCAL
    # Just a member server
    domain master = no
    local master = no
    preferred master = no
    # Disable printing error log messages when CUPS is not installed.
    printcap name = /etc/printcap
    load printers = no
    # Works both in samba 3.2 and 3.6.
    idmap backend = tdb
    idmap uid = 10000-99999
    idmap gid = 10000-99999
    # no .tld
    idmap config EXAMPLE:backend = rid
    idmap config EXAMPLE:range = 10000-99999
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    # This way users log in with username instead of username@example.org
    winbind use default domain = yes
    # Inherit groups in groups
    winbind nested groups = yes
    winbind refresh tickets = yes
    winbind offline logon = true
    # Becomes /home/example/username
    template homedir = /home/%D/%U
    # No shell access
    template shell = /bin/false
    client use spnego = yes
    client ntlmv2 auth = yes
    encrypt passwords = yes
    restrict anonymous = 2
    log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
    log level = 2

[Dropbox]
    comment = Daily Emptied Dropbox
    path = /sharing/test
    valid users = "@EXAMPLE\Domain Users"
    force group = "domain users"
    writable = yes
    read only = no
    force create mode = 0660
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
    force directory mode = 0770
    access based share enum = yes
    hide unreadable = yes
```

nsswitch.conf=

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files winbind
group:          files windind
shadow:         files windind
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

(tested with `compat` instead of `files`, same results)

How can i get AD Groups to work ?

Comment: You should use `winbind` not `windind`, like so: passwd: files winbind group: files windind shadow: files windind

Answer (score 1):

You need to apt-get install libnss-winbind libpam-winbind. Its make some links in you system to force getent through winbind. worked for me ubuntu 16 samba 4.3.11

Comment: I've experienced the same issue and the packages which you've mentioned were missing. After Installing them everything starts to working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this to help others that may have the same issues I had:

- getent group @<domain.name> returns nothing
- AD group based logins not working
- AD individual user based logins ARE working

After much troubleshooting I discovered that the /etc/resolv.conf provided by systemd-resolved was incompatible with sssd and AD group logins.  Sssd was allowing users when added them individually using sudo realm permit @<domain.name> but not with sudo realm permit -g @<domain.name>.

In /etcv/resolv.conf replace 120.0.0.53 with the domain controller IPs in your network.  You may need to netplan apply and you can restart sssd for good measure.   Group based AD logins started working after that, I've tested this several times and the fix is consistent.

Ben